# Censored Dummy Regressor

Tags: predictor, discrete-data, categorical-encoding

I have a dataset that contains factors corresponding income ranges of sampled persons, like people with factor 1 earn between 10,000 to 20,000, 2 between 20,000 to 30,000 . I could just make  dummies for those ranges. But the factor variable for income is right censored. The norm is adding an extra dummy for censored/uncensored category, but this would lead to bias, according to some published papers. What is the best way to approach this problem? The dependent variable is discrete choice.

Comment: btw, my goal is inference...

Comment: Chi-square test should fit your needs if you bin your variables into factors.